# How to find the most left point in a Triangle?

Tags: java, oop

I have this problem:
I have this class named Point:

```
class Point {
private double x;
private double y;

public Point(final double x, final double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}
```

}

I have a class Triangle:

```
class Triangle {
private Point a;
private Point b;
private Point c;

public Triangle(Point a, Point b , Point c){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public double area() {
    double area = (a.getX() * (b.getY()- c.getY()) +
            b.getX() * (c.getY() - a.getY()) + c.getX() * (a.getY() - b.getY())) / 2.0;
    return Math.abs(area);
}

@Override
public String pointsToString() {
    return "("+a.getX()+","+a.getY()+")"+"("+b.getX()+","+b.getY()+")"+"("+c.getX()+","+c.getY()+")";
}

public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "[" + pointsToString() + "]";
}

@Override
public Point leftmostPoint() {
    return null;
}
```

}

The question is how to find the leftmost point in the Triangle ?

I should realize the method leftmostPoint(). The method leftmostPoint() should return leftmost point of the Triangle: the one having the least X coordinate and if there are many leftmost points, return any of them.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how triangles work. The leftmost point (or one of them, if there are more than one) must be one of the 3 corners. So, it's a, b, or c.

Just compare a to b, and then the winner of that to c, and return the winner of that.

Answer (score 0):

the least X coordinate of a Triangle will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).